# Having problem in understanding REDUX code

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, redux, action, spread

I am trying to create shopping basket through Redux Toolkit. I am finding it hard to understand this piece of code that what is purpose of all this code. Specifically those if conditions. Cant understand how add and remove reducer is working

```
const basketSlice = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    add: (state, action) => {
      return state.map(item => {
        if (item.id !== action.payload.id) {
          return item
        }

        return {
          ...item,
          added: true
        }
      })
    },
    remove: (state, action) => {
      return state.map(item => {
        if (item.id !== action.payload.id) {
          return item
        }

        return {
          ...item,
          added: false
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Basically it loops over the `state` items, creating a new array from what is returned in each iteration of the loop.

So, what it does for, say, the `remove` reducer:

- Loop over each item in state, each time returning something that will be an entry in the new array
- The `if` section checks if *the `id` of the current loop element is the same than the one we want to remove*: if it's not the same ID, we return the item "as is", if it's the same ID, *we return added: false* so we know it was removed.
- In the end, you get a new array that was processed through this `map` function, allowing to do whatever check you need to.

Say I have an array with 3 items:

```js
const state = [
 { id: 12, name: "Fancy Phone", added: true, },
 { id: 54, name: "Leather Jacket", added: true, },
 { id: 564, name: "AI World-Dominating Robot", added: true, },
]
```

And I want to remove the "AI World-Dominating Robot" because I don't want anymore trouble:

```js
// Create a new array from the .map
return state.map(item => {
  // here we loop over each item one by one
  // IF the ID in the action payload (thus the ID you want to remove) is not the same as the current item ID, we don't want to remove it
  if (action.payload.id !== item.id) {
    return item // so we return the item "as-is", and as we returned something, the .map loop moves to the next item
  }
  return { ...item, added: false } // otherwise, we set "added: false" to flag the fact it's removed
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. when we want to return the state why are we using
...item

Comment: Because you use the original `item` to "rebuild" a new array. 
So you just return `item` when you don't want to change it, but you change the `added` part when `item` is the item you want to remove